# Django - Updated data is not saving to db

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I want to change `Branch` field of `Blank` model in a given range. For example, changing `Blank` model's `Branch` field with numbers from 1 to 3. Here are my codes:

`views.py`:

```
@login_required(login_url='sign-in')
def blanks(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'create-blank' in request.POST:
        form = CreateBlankForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    # here happens updating process
    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'share-blank' in request.POST:
        form = CreateBlankForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.update()
    else:  
        form = CreateBlankForm()

    blank_list = Blank.objects.all().order_by('-created')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'blank.html', context)
```

`forms.py`:

```
class CreateBlankForm(ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=False):
        blank = super(CreateBlankForm, self).save(commit=False)
        number_of_objects = range(blank.number_from, blank.number_to+1)

        for i in number_of_objects:
            Blank.objects.create(
                blank_series = blank.blank_series,
                blank_number = i,
                branch=blank.branch,
                number_from = blank.number_from,
                number_to = blank.number_to                
            )

    def update(self, commit=False):
        shared_blank = super(CreateBlankForm, self).update(commit=False) 
        number_of_objects = range(shared_blank.number_from, shared_blank.number_to+1)

        for i in number_of_objects:
            Blank.objects.update(
                branch=shared_blank.branch
            )
```

`models.py`:

```
class Blank(models.Model):
    blank_series = models.CharField(_('Blankın seriyası'), max_length=3)
    blank_number = models.IntegerField(_('Blankın nömrəsi'), blank=True, null=True)

    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    number_from = models.IntegerField()
    number_to = models.IntegerField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.blank_series
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in update method use:

```
instance.branch = new value of branch 
instance.save()
return instance
```

Comment: Is everything okay with `views.py` ?

Comment: it seems okay! 
try with debugging

p.s. instead of useing for loop
try this:
update_arr = []
for obj in number_of_objects:
   obj.branch = shared_blank.branch
   update_arr.append(obj)

Blank.objects.bulk_update(update_arr, ['branch'])

try to use bulk update instead calling update method multiple times
and make sure in 
for obj in number_of_objects: each obj is type of blank model 
to work your code properly make sure you pass id of obj which you want to update in for loop in forms.py

i think that will surely works

Answer (score 0):

it seems okay!
try with debugging

p.s. instead of useing for loop
try this:

```
update_arr = []
for obj in number_of_objects:
   obj.branch = shared_blank.branch
   update_arr.append(obj)

Blank.objects.bulk_update(update_arr, ['branch'])
```

try to use bulk update instead calling update method multiple times
and make sure in
for obj in number_of_objects: each obj is type of blank model
to work your code properly make sure **you pass id** of obj which you want to update in for loop in forms.py

i think that will surely works

Comment: Now my update method is like:

```
    def update(self):
        shared_blank = super(CreateBlankForm, self).update(commit=False) 
        number_of_objects = range(shared_blank.number_from, shared_blank.number_to+1)
        update_arr = []
        for obj in number_of_objects:
            obj.branch = shared_blank.branch
            update_arr.append(obj)

        Blank.objects.bulk_update(update_arr, ['branch'])
```

but doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

it seems there's issue in this snippet

```
def update(self, commit=False):
    shared_blank = super(CreateBlankForm, self).update(commit=False) 
    number_of_objects = range(shared_blank.number_from, shared_blank.number_to+1)

    for i in number_of_objects:
        Blank.objects.update(
            branch=shared_blank.branch
        )
```

Blank.objects.update(
branch=shared_blank.branch
)
of which id obj you want to update branch value is not defined here
try to pass id as well in obj